# Rails Controller / Action Specific 404 Not Found View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's not that hard to setup a custom 404 not_found page for Rails using `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` for example. But the custom view will be rendered for any 404 error such as `ActionController::RoutingError`, `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` or `AbstractController::RecordNotFound` and for all actions and controllers. How can I render a custom 404 only for `ActionController::RecordNotFound` in one specific action (like Users#show) ? I was thinking of something like that but seems ugly and doesn't work :

```
def set_user
 @user = User.find_by_something(params[:something]) || render 'errors/not_found'
end

def show
 set_user
end
```

*** Edit ***

I actually misled the answerer by not posting the full code ;(, sorry. I edited my answer and we found a solution, see the accepted answer.

*** This also worked but maybe isn't the best solution ***

```
def set_user
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def show
 set_user
 if @user.nil?
  render 'errors/not_found' and return
 end
 # Code goes here when code 200
end
```

Comment: why don't you use `@user = User.find(params[:id]) rescue ActionController::RecordNotFound => e  render 'errors/not_found'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rescue should do the trick here...

```
def set_user
 @user = User.find_by_something(params[:id])
end

def show
 begin
   set_user
   raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @user.nil?
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
   render 'errors/not_found' and return
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start. I can render the page but I have some code running after `set_user` actually. Is there a way to stop the execution after rendering the `not_found` page ? Because it's dependent on @user and so I have a 500 now.

Comment: I just mean that the show action and view are still rendered I don't want that.

Comment: Sorry I just saw I didn't post the full code. What rendered the error page was my code in the show action as you can see in my question, now edited. Adding return on render there made it work. I'll +1 your solution but should I accept the one I have in my post or yours as accepted answer ?

Comment: As per your edit in the question I think rails find would raise an exception it wouldn't give nil...are you using find_by_id or may be User.where(params[:id]) by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I simplified the question but I shouldn't have, it seems like. The actual model is `Codex` and i'm doing `Codex.find_by_codex(params[:codex])`. I'm a mess.

Comment: Now I get it. I'll edit the post accordingly please use that instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87284/discussion-between-karim-mortabit-and-vamsi-krishna).

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but I think that a better solution for that would be making your `UsersController` rescue from an error and then render some custom error view.

So, do the following in your `UsersController`:

```rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404

# Your old set_user but raising an error
def set_user
  @user = User.find_by_something(params[:something])
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @user
end

private

def render_404
  render 'users/not_found', status: '404', layout: 'errors'
end
```

Now just define a custom error page for your `UsersController` at `app/views/users/not_found.html.erb` and a custom layout file (only if you set `layout: 'errors'`) at `app/views/layouts/errors.html.erb`.